# Visual Studio Breakpoint at page allocation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to find the cause of an access violation within a library that always seems to occur at a certain page limit (an address like 0x06B12000).

Now I'm trying to trace the page allocations to find out if the program misses out on some point, but VirtualAlloc only seems to get called a handful of times during program start and not later on.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try using specific tool for the job. Enabling CRT Debug Heap might be a good start.

Comment: Have a look at the Application Verifier from Microsoft. It has options to isolate allocations in different pages with guard space (unallocated pages) before and after.

Comment: I don't have admin rights on my machine.

Comment: `VirtualAlloc` gets called internally from the C/C++ run-time library and only if the heap management implemented there has exhausted its free storage. You might try overriding `operator new` or `malloc` and plant a hook there.

Comment: Is the library a `*.lib` or `*.dll`?

Comment: A dll. Closed source.

Comment: Does it come in separate debug and release versions or is it just one file?
Is it a C or a C++ library?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint on `malloc` via "Break at Function". The Studio comes with some source code for its runtime library so you can debug in there.

Once you have hit this breakpoint you can add a condition to it to make it only trigger if the returned memory contains the address you are looking for.
Something like `(res <= 0x....) && (0x.... < res + nSize)`. This would work for VS2010 debug builds.

Release builds are more difficult since some of the local variables are only kept in registers.